# Layer Shadow Missing on iPad3 (but works in Simulator)

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-graphics, shadow

I draw a shadow behind a UIView using the following code

```
    self.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 25.0;
    self.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
    self.view.clipsToBounds = NO;

    CGPathRef shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.layer.bounds].CGPath;
    [self.view.layer setShadowPath:shadowPath];
```

This works as supposed in the Simulator and on the iPhone5. However on my iPad3: No Shadow at all.

[image]

Any idea how come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutions. It wasn't about the Simulator. It was about the return of bounds in portrait vs. landscapt orientation. I had to move the setting of the shadow path into the **viewDidAppear** and the **didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation** method to have the shadow render correctly in all possible startup orientations.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    CGPathRef shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.layer.bounds].CGPath;
    [self.view.layer setShadowPath:shadowPath];
}

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    CGPathRef shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.layer.bounds].CGPath;
    [self.view.layer setShadowPath:shadowPath];
}
```